# Ruby on Rails > Action Pack APIs > Getting images from website to windows phone 7 app

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-7, dynamic, listbox

I have an application for Windows Phone 7 that is in its final stages. All I have left to do is allow content I post on my website, from user submissions, to make its way into the phone application's `listbox` as a new `listboxitem` for each image.

Some background:

I have a website made in HTML from dreamweaver, and I have installed Ruby on Rails software for it. I am at the point where I need to obtain the set of APIs that the phone can communicate with in order to receive the image data from the website to the phone.

I am thinking of using Action Pack APIs (action web service), and exporting the data in XML. Technically speaking, is this possible? Is there a better set of APIs to use (free of course)?

As I have never done this before, will what I plan on do be fine in terms of having my phone gain the image data I need to dynamically populate a listbox in my application?

Thank you,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

is something like this would help?

[windows phone 7 twitter appliaction](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx)

The standard approach is parse your web content and binding data into your listbox on wp7

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible to get images from a website and display them in a list box. The only issue you'll have if you're controlling the backend/website is formatting the output. If you can expose a list of Uris to the images in an XML format your task shoudl be really simple.